# Regexes allow only [a-z][A-Z][0-9] and -

Tags: regex

please I am a novice when it comes to regexes, Using search and replace, how can i allow only a-z, A-Z, 0.9 and - on a link, E.g

```
https://example.com/dav,ido song/ will be replaced with https://example.com/dav-ido-song/

https://example.com/dav,i'do/ will be replaced with https://example.com/dav-i-do/
```

i want this to be replace using $1,$2 etc as substitutiion, I am using this in a wp plugin search and replace and i am only restricted to $1,2,3 etc as substitutiion.

i have tried this `([^\w\s]+)` to replace with $1 but its still giving me the same output as before.

Comment: You probably just want [sanitize_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/) (or sanitize_title_with_dashes()) which already does this.

Comment: However if you did want your own regex it might be easier to do a search for things that aren't 'a-zA-Z0-9\-', and replace all of them with '-'.

Comment: @Rup how can i archieve this using search and replace